# Counting zeros of a rational function in the open unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

> How many distinct $z \in \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1\}$ satisfy $$h(z)=\frac{z^3 + 5z^2 + 1}{z+6}=0?$$

I know the function's singularity at $z=-6$ is outside the region with which we need concern ourselves, so we should be able to apply Rouche's Theorem:

> Let $U \in \mathbb{C}$ be an open set and let $f,g \in \mathcal{O}(U)$ not identically zero in any connected component of $U$.  Let $\gamma$ be a cycle which is zero-homologous in $U$ such that, for all points $z$ in the image of $\gamma$, $$|f(z)-g(z)| < |f(z)|.$$
>
> Then, $$\sum_{z \in Z_f} \eta(\gamma; z) \mathsf{ord}(f;z) =\sum_{z \in Z_g} \eta(\gamma; z) \mathsf{ord}(g;z)$$

However, finding a function with easily countable zeros that will satisfy the suppositions of Rouche's theorem is giving me trouble.

Please advise.

Comment: the zeroes of $h$ are the zeroes of the numerator which is a cubic; can you finish from here?

Comment: You are looking for the zeros of $g(z) = z^3+5z^2 +1$ in the unit disk, and you need a function $f$ with the property that $f(z)$ is “large” and $f(z)-g(z)$ is “small” for $|z|=1$. Does that give you an idea how to choose $f$?

Comment: I believe so.  $|5z^2| =5$ when $|z|=1$ and $|z^3 +1| \leq 2$.  $5z^2$ has a zero of multiplicity 2 at $z=0$.  So $g(z)$ will also have two zeros in the unit disk.  I think those zeros are distinct, but how can I know for sure?

Comment: For any double root  $z_0$ we have $g'(z_0)=0.$

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry for forgetting basic facts, turns out the new stuff doesn't make the old stuff go away.  Should I answer my own question, or just leave it?